# Loading a Picturebox in C# with an Oracle Blob

Tags: c#, oracle, blob, picturebox

I've a very basic form with just one picture box,one textfield and one button. I've created a table in Oracle to store a blob, **I want to load that image into a picturebox in c# once the button is clicked**. Here is what I've wrote so far.

My picturebox name = "picBoxXray". My textbox name = "txtXrayId". My button name = "btnGetXrayID". And My table name is "XRay".

```
    private void btnGetXrayID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (txtXrayId.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("XrayID be entered");
        }

        if (picBoxXray.Image != null)        
        { 
            picBoxXray.Image.Dispose();         
        }

        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
            Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
                              connection.ConnectionString);

            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM XRay WHERE XrayID =" + txtXrayId.Text;

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // Obtain the image
                //Need code

            }

            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

    }
```

Any help would be greatly aprreciated, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the image from a stream, for example:

```
public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Then aassign the image to the picture box. the byteArray in is the blob you read from the db. of course the image have to be stored in a format known ( png/jpeg for instance )